# Why does islam encourage covering female bodies?

Tags: hijab

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijab#Modern_history):

> Koran says: Say to the believing men that they cast down their looks and guard their private parts; that is purer for them; surely Allah is Aware of what they do. And say to the believing women that they should lower their gaze and guard their private parts; that they should not display their beauty and ornaments except what (must ordinarily) appear thereof; that they should draw their khimār over their breasts and not display their beauty except to their husband, their fathers, their husband's fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers or their brothers' sons, or their sisters' sons, or their women, or the slaves whom their right hands possess, or male servants free of physical needs, or small children who have no sense of the shame of sex; and that they should not strike their feet in order to draw attention to their hidden ornaments. — Quran 24:30

There are also some hadith supplied.

However, nowhere does it explain **WHY**.

Why does Islam encourage covering female bodies?

1. Is it because to keep society civil?
2. Is it to protect women from sexual harm?
3. Is it because to preserve modesty?
4. anything else?

Please, answer with appropriate authentic references.

Comment: It is to prevent adultery and fornication spread in the society.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

### Why does islam encourage covering female bodies?

In order to understand why Islam encourage covering female bodies, one must first understand concept of Fahisha (adultery) in Islam and Allah's position towards it. Following verse is a starting point

> And do not go near the adultery; it was always an immorality and an
> evil way
>
> [Quran 17:32 (page 42)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH17_SuraAlIsraa_Verses2-35.pdf)

So Fahisha (adultery) is a grave sin and in following Hadith narration Imam Muhammad Al-Baqir explains it.

> (It has been narrated) from Abu Ja’far (asws) regarding His (azwj)
> Words: **And do not go near the adultery; it was always an
> immorality**. He (asws) said: ‘A disobedience and an abomination, for
> Allah (azwj) Abhors it and Hates it. And His (azwj) Words: **and an
> evil way** - and it (deserves) the harshest of the Punishment for the
> people. And the adultery is the biggest of the major sins’.
>
> [TafseerHub-e-Ali (page 42)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH17_SuraAlIsraa_Verses2-35.pdf)

Since adultery (fornication) is such an ugly sin in the sight of Allah (SWT), it should not be allowed to spread in society. And in order to ensure this, Allah (SWT) has ordered to implement a number of measures. Covering the female body is one such measure. To better understand why the covering of a woman's body is necessary, we need to study the following verse.

> **There have been adorned for the people, the love of desires, of the women** and the sons and hoards, the hoard of gold and silver, and
> well bred horses and cattle and tilth. That is a provision of the life
> of the world; and Allah, with Him is the good return
>
> [Quran 3:14 (page 24)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH3_SuraAaleImraan_Verses1-34.pdf)

This verse explains how the Nafs (desire or maybe psychology) of a person is created and what this Nafs strives for. As you can see, Nafs strives for several things. Among these things, the woman is being put first. It should be concluded that if women walk openly in the society showing their bodies to men, it will arouse their lust and eventually lead to adultery between men and women.

**Conclusion**

Why does Islam encourage covering female bodies?

It is one of the measures that ensure that Fahisha (adultery) does not spread in society.

Comment: This answer gives rise to another question: as far as I realize, adultery and fornication are visibly much lower among Amazon tribes, although they don't wear clothes.

Comment: The word "Fahisha" is translated into English as "Adultery" or "Fornication" whereas it has much broader meaning. It includes "indecency", "ugliness" and "corruption" as well. Try to contemplate again with these meanings.

Answer (score -4):

The actual truth is that the Quran does not command hijab. Allah mentions the word "khimar", which was a head covering worn by Arab women before Islam was revealed. The problem was, the society at the time was promiscuous. Women were not covering their chest area. That is why the command came for women to take their ALREADY WORN khimar and to cover their chest area. Notice how Allah mentions khimar, but he doesn't explicitly command it.

As for hadiths, there is not a single AUTHENTIC one that commands hijab, niqab, jilbaab, or burka. There are authentic hadiths of what the Prophet's wives did, but that was their own personal sunnah. That is what they did. No where did they command that this is the only specific way for women to dress. And as you know, sunnah is not fardh.

Some Muslims say that it is because of colonialism that many Muslim women do not wear hijab. While this is true (European and Soviet colonizers heavily secularized and liberalized much of the Muslim world), it is also wrong. Many historical Muslim cultures (like the subcontinent, so that is present day Pakistan, India, and Bangladesh) had no concept of hijab or niqab. This is why, to this day, the majority of Muslim women from Pakistan, India, and Bangladesh do not wear hijab. They wear their traditional clothes, which has been worn for over a thousand years by Muslim women from the subcontinent. Islamic empires ruled nearly all of the subcontinent for 1300 years, and the ulema and rulers never issued fatwas for women to wear hijab or niqab.

So, what should Muslim women wear? They should wear clothes that are not tight, short, see through, or revealing. More specifically, they should avoid clothes that show off the breasts, butt, vagina, and legs. These body parts of women cause sexual arousal in men. Trust me, I'm a man who was born and raised in the sexually open West. I know what arouses men. I know what arouses teen boys. It isn't just the sight of women, but it is the body parts which I mentioned. As well, Muslim women should not have behaviour that is sexual. This can be done by women who are completely covered head to toe, or it can be done by women who are dressed inappropriately.

These two videos explain a lot more of what I already mentioned:
https://youtu.be/Dz9Fq_-rC3g

https://youtu.be/Q1id1NaxFbA

Comment: Please, add reference/citation in favor of your statements. YouTube vidos are not references.

Comment: Shabir Ally, Javed Ghamdi, Abu Layth. And yes, Youtube videos are references.

Comment: You already received 3 down-votes. No one has time to watch multiple videos. Add text references.  If you don't add references, I will cast another down-vote.

Comment: My answers will get downvoted regardless. This is a given when dealing with Muslims online who raid out other views and understandings of Islam.

Comment: If you don't attach text references, your answer would not carry any validity. You can blame after you attach references.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't matter. My answers/questions WILL get downvoted because they don't meet a certain "level" of Islam. Same goes for Reddit. Muslims on social media platforms are usually Salafi's. Salafi's will not allow other views of Islam.

Comment: @Ali this isn't social media, this site has a decorum, no matter if you are speaking the truth or not, you must give direct references to Qur'an, Hadith, or valuable scholarly Fatwas that are largely agreed upon. Oh and also, Salafis are here on this site, just a piece of small good news for you ;)

Comment: @Ali If you give notice, this is a StackExchange site, these sites are different and have a QNA standard. Take a look at: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer